# Tracking Internal Campaigns (custom variables)

Tags: google-analytics

Currently, we are using utm variables to track internal campaigns on our site, but I've since learned that is the incorrect way of using UTM Variables. We lose the previous UTM variables that resulted in the person visiting our site and apparently it creates a new session as well.

So, I read this article (http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2012/01/26/track-conversions-internal-external-campaigns/) and decided to set up custom variables that would trigger on events and track internal campaigns that way.

After a few days of implementing, the events and custom variables are triggering and being logged by Google Analytics. The problem is our "goal" is on a separate subdomain (that is being tracked). Unfortunately, it looks like the session level custom variables are not carrying over to that subdomain. So, in Google Analytics I can see that someone clicked on a link, but I'm not able to see if they actually completed the goal.

Any idea on what I can do about this? Am I taking the wrong approach for tracking internal campaigns?

Just for a little more context: Our site is a non-profit where the ultimate goal is for someone to make a donation (which occurs on a subdomain), we want to be able to track which internal links/pages are resulting in donations.

Answer (score 1):

To carry the session level custom variable set on site.com over to sub.site.com, you need to avoid starting a second session. A second session will begin when GA detects a new traffic source, and this is exactly what happens you cross to the subdomain if you are not sharing the _utmz cookie (campaign cookie): GA writes a new cookie that says the traffic source changed to a referral from site.com. The solution is to share cookies by adding a line of code to both site.com and sub.site.com: _gaq.push(['_setDomainName','site.com']); See the following documentation for more info: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Comment: That's what I thought, but it still isn't carrying over. I'm thinking I need to also include _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
 on both sites and use _gaq.push(['_link', this.href]); return false;" on the referring link.